# How do you format a datagridview column that is connected to a datasource?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Current screenshot:
[image: my current DataGridView screenshot]

I'd like to format the displayed value in the datagridview in the picture to two decimals, i wanted to make the change at display so i still have my orignal values untouched.

### I've tried it placing the format in code

- before, (At Form's New Sub)
- after assigning the datagridview's datasource, (at Form's New Sub)
- and also placing it in the designer, (datagridviewtextboxcolumn.defaultcellstyle)

still the values in the datagridview didnt change

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in form load:

```
 dataGridView.Columns["Total"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

OR

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender,DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == indexOfColumn)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Format = "N2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Private Sub CraneCtl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn22.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
    End Sub


Tried placing it , still didn't change


thanks for the help though

Comment: See the above method. Its in c#. Please change the indexOfColumn to the index of the column